# Typescript Array of functions can't infer type of argument

Tags: typescript

I have the following type definition:

```js
type FnList = [...((a: string, b: string) => void)[], (a: string) => void]
```

When I try to use it, typescript can't infer the type of the last function's argument:

```js
const newList: FnList = [
  (a, b) => {}, //Infered >> a: string, b: string
  (a, b) => {}, //Infered >> a: string, b: string
  (a) => {}, // Error --> Parameter 'a' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)
]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think contextual typing and leading/middle rest elements don't play nicely together; see [ms/TS#45972](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45972) for a similar but not identical issue.  I don't think there's going to be a "fix" for this that isn't a workaround.  Are you okay with workarounds, say one of the form `const newList: FnList = fnList(...)` where `...` is some set of arguments including those callbacks?

Comment: Oddly enough, this works when `(a: string) => void` is first (before the rest elements)... https://tsplay.dev/mbQv2N

Comment: I would say that's expected, since rest elements traditionally come at the end (they were introduced to support rest *parameters* after all) and TS is optimized for the regular case.  Initial/leading rest elements are weird.  Anyway, [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAr81W) is the workaround I'd use if, for some reason, we really need the `FnList` type.  I suppose a description of the use case would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try put the destructured elements at the end, like this:

```
type FnList = [(c: string) => void, ...((a: string, b: string) => void)[]]
const newList: FnList = [
  (c) => {}, 
  (a, b) => {}, //Infered >> a: string, b: string
  (c, d) => {}, //Infered >> a: string, b: string
]
```

The spread operator captures the remaining elements of an array, so what makes sense is to put first the specific types first and for all the rest the ones from the spread operator.